# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::save() - Yii framework

Tags: php, yii

I use Yii Framework, and in my code, I have :

```
$model=partidascapturainfo::model()->findByAttributes(array('capturainfoid'=>$idCaptura,'metricaid'=>$metricaId,'proyectoproductoid'=>$productoId));

if ($model!==null){
                    if($model->save()){
                        $response->status = "1";
                        $response->message= "La Informacion se subio correctamente con el  Id ".$idCaptura;
                        $this->logInFile("model->save() ok");
                    }else{

                        $response->status = "0";
                        $response->message= "La Informacion no fue enviada intentelo mas tarde";
                        $this->logInFile("model->save() not posible-model:".print_r($model->getErrors()));
                    }
                }else{
                    $this->logInFile("model is null");
                    $this->logInFile(print_r($model->getErrors()));

                }
```

I'm a java programer so, I'm not so familiar with PHP, but, I can see $model is not null.
However, I can't find a way to display content of $model:

```
print_r($model); // display 1   
get_object_vars($model); // display Array
var_dump($model); // display nothing
```

It is necessary to say that I send the request from a PhoneGap app in Android, to a php script.
I take and upload the foto, and send the request. So I can't debug in firebug for instance.

The only way I found is write a log file with datas ( $this->logInFile())

I don't know how to resolve this... In other topics, they say exception happens because $model is null, but mine is not...

In the same way, it would be a great help to be able to log sql query that is executed by :

```
model()->findByAttributes(array('capturainfoid'=>$idCaptura,'metricaid'=>$metricaId,'proyectoproductoid'=>$productoId));
```

Log in File Function :

```
function logInFile($msg){
    $path = "/logs/logfile.log";
    $f = @fopen(getcwd().$path, 'a+');
    //$req = json_encode($_REQUEST);
    //@fputs($f, date("Y/m/d g:i:s").$req."\n");
    @fputs($f, $msg."\n");
    @fclose($f);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are explicitly checking for null (!== null) so if the model is an empty object that will not be caught by this check.

For debug use

```
print_r($model, true)
```

or

```
var_export($model, true)
```

The current calls you are using flush the info to the default output and are useful on console calls. Setting the return parameter true, prints out the info.

Comment: Tx for your answer. I tried : if (emtpy($model)), and $model is not empty nor null. also, I want to print $model in log file, and : $this->logInFile("captura:".print_r($captura, true)); is just displaying :"captura".

Comment: can you split the first line. It is difficult to understand what you are trying to do there:    partidascapturainfo::model()->findByAttributes(array('capturainfoid'=>$idCaptura,'metricaid'=>$metricaId,'proyectoproductoid'=>$productoId));

Comment: It seems to be part of Yii framework, it should make a sql query with the 3 arguments.

Comment: And what is the return value of the findByAttributes function if no matching result is found?

Comment: null. --> http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#findByAttributes-detail